# Select into an object which recursively references itself

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have the following entity:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int PreviousEntityId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PreviousEntityId")]
    public virtual MyEntity PreviousEntity { get; set; }
}
```

and the following DAO:

```
public class MyDao
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public MyDao PreviousDao { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to use LINQ to Entities to map MyEntity into MyDao, including the PreviousDao in the selected object but not traversing further down the chain of entities:

```
var result = context.MyEntities.Select(entity => new MyDao
{
    Id = entity.Id,
    PreviousDao = new MyDao
    {
        Id = entity.PreviousEntityId
    }
}).ToList();
```

This does not work, due to the following error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'The type 'MyDao' appears in two structurally incompatible initializations within a single LINQ to Entities query. A type can be initialized in two places in the same query, but only if the same properties are set in both places and those properties are set in the same order.'

Attempting to set the property in the child object to `null`:

```
var result = context.MyEntities.Select(entity => new MyDao
{
    Id = entity.Id,
    PreviousDao = new MyDao
    {
        Id = entity.PreviousEntityId,
        PreviousDao = null
    }
}).ToList();
```

gives a different error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'Unable to create a null constant value of type 'MyDao'. Only entity types, enumeration types or primitive types are supported in this context.'

Is there any way to populate the `PreviousDao` property in the LINQ query? It does not seem like there is a way to terminate the recursion - Entity requires both properties to always be set, which means any child object will need to define its own child object, and so forth.

Comment: If it helps: you could have a table-valued UDF or stored procedure which does the query using a recursive CTE, and have Linq just hoover-up the end-output.

Comment: Try selecting just the Id and PreviousId into an anonymous class, then do an `AsEnumerable` and then do your `Select` that populates your class.

Comment: @juharr IRL this is a somewhat more complex object. I might have to opt for this kind of approach (keeping just the IDs, executing the query, then populating the object in another query), but I'd prefer a solution which does not force me to enumerate the `Select` and lets me eg. return a `IQueryable<MyDao>`.

Comment: If you want to do that so that you can do more filtering on the result I'd recommend instead updating the method to take any filters you might need so they will be applied before you return data from the DB.  Long story short is that you are limited in what you can select in a query to entities, primitive types, and anonymous classes because Linq wouldn't know how to translate anything else into SQL if you did have a `Where` after that `Select`.